# Deallocate Tab View iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am currently testing my app, and when I switch tab views I notice that my allocation of memory goes up, and stays up. From this I have to assume it has to do with loading new information from the new view and not unloading the old view. So essentially I have two views loaded. I would liked to know how I can remove the prior view from memory, or if that is even necessary. I am currently running at about 50mb of allocation (yeh it is a small app). I don't have any leaks.

Also, I created my tabview by "embedding" my existing views in one, so I don't have any code currently to support it.

Comment: Please don't over-optimize. Don't just look at the numbers. Maybe your app is using 70 MB because it has 70 MB available to it.

Comment: You shouldn't remove the previous views; this is the way tab bar controllers work. When you click on a tab, that controller's view is loaded. Once you've been to all the tabs, the memory will stop going up (at least because of new views being loaded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rdelmar speaks truth. A tab bar controller keeps the child view controllers in it's tabs for the life of the tab bar controller.

A view controllers views don't get loaded until the first time it is displayed. The views can use a substantial amount of memory.

All that is perfectly normal, and you should not try to change it.